# Cannot open include file in .cu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have a visual studio c++ project (with VS 2010 and insight 2) which contains a cuda file. Here's the code

Hello.h :

```
#pragma once

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include "thrust\device_vector.h"
#pragma warning(pop)

class Hello
{
public:
    Hello( const thrust::host_vector<unsigned long>& data );
    unsigned long Sum();
    unsigned long Max();

private:
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned long> m_data;
}
```

Hello.cu :

```
#include "thrust\host_vector.h"
#include "thrust\device_vector.h"
#include "thrust\extrema.h"

#include "Hello.h"

using namespace ::thrust;

Hello::Hello( const thrust::host_vector<unsigned long>& data )
    : m_data( data.cbegin(), data.cend() )
{
}

unsigned long
Hello::Sum()
{
    return( reduce( m_data.cbegin(), m_data.cend(), 
        ( unsigned long )0,
        plus<unsigned long>() ) );
}

unsigned long
Hello::Max()
{
    return( *max_element( m_data.cbegin(), m_data.cend() ) );
}
```

and finally main.cpp :

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define WINDOWS _LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #define NOMINMAX
    #include <Windows.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ppl.h> //parallel patterns library

#include "Hello.h"

using namespace ::Concurrency;

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    printf( "Generating data...\n" );
    thrust::host_vector<unsigned long> host_data( 100000 );
    thrust::generate( host_data.begin(), host_data.end(), rand );
    printf( "generated %d numbers\n", host_data.size() );

    parallel_invoke(
        [host_data]()
    {
        printf( "\nRunning host code...\n" );
        unsigned long host_result = thrust::reduce( host_data.cbegin(),
            host_data.cend(), 0, thrust::plus<unsigned long>() );
        printf( "The sum is %d\n", host_result );

        host_result = *thrust::max_element( host_data.cbegin(), 
            host_data.cend(), thrust::less<unsigned long>() );
        printf( "The max is %d\n", host_result );
    },
        [host_data]()
    {
        printf( "\nCopying data to device...\n" );
        Hello hello( host_data );

        printf( "\nRunning CUDA device code...\n" );
        unsigned long device_result = hello.Sum();
        printf( "The sum is %d\n", device_result );

        printf( "\nRunning CUDA device code...\n" );
        device_result = hello.Max();
        printf( "The max is %d\n", device_result );
    }
    );

    return( 0 );
}
```

This code comes from : [here](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-and-cuda-easier-with-rc2/)

My problem is that when I build the project, it gives me this error:

```
Hello.cu(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hello.h': No such file or  directory
```

However, when I right click on the "include "Hello.h"" it finds the file just fine.

I've added the folder where my .h are in the additionnal include directories of the project. So I really don't know why it couldn't open the file.

I don't know if it's more of a configuration problem of just maybe a c++ thing I forgot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .cu file will have most likely have a custom build rule to make use of NVCC. Right-click the .cu file and look at its properties. The build rule will again contain a section for additional include directories. Make sure the directory containing your header is present there as well.